# Mongoose SUM + $cond + array field

Tags: node.js, mongoose, aggregate-functions

```
"payments": [
          {
            "_id": "57bea755acfbfc4e37c3dfdf",
            "user": "57b1c3d2d591a46848c25f45",
            "transferred_amount": 10,
            "transaction_type": "refund",
            "reason": "#1968 shop box refunded",
            "__v": 0
          },
          {
            "_id": "57beb883acfbfc4e37c3dfe0",
            "user": "57b1c3d2d591a46848c25f45",
            "transferred_amount": 10,
            "transaction_type": "payout",
            "reason": "#1968 shop box refunded",
            "__v": 0
          }
        ]
```

this is my db data.

```
Model.aggragate().project({
            paid_out_amount: {
            $sum: {
                $cond: [{
                    $eq: ['$payments.transaction_type', 'payout']
                }, 0, '$payments.transferred_amount']
            }
        }
})
```

This is my node code to fetch those data. I'm trying sum **payout amount** alone and store it into a field. Here $cond always returns zero. can anyone help me out.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using `$unwind` operator.

Like:

```
Model.aggregate([
{ $unwind: "$payments" },
{
    $group:
         {
           _id: null,
           paid_out_amount: { $sum: {$cond: [ { $eq: [ "$payments.transaction_type", 'payout' ] }, '$payments.transferred_amount', 0 ] } }
         }
}
]);
```

I assume that you want to add all `transferred_amount` of `payout` type and return total sum that's why use `_id:null`. if need you can add fieldName for group by